# How to access Firebase Database node using contains() method?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an app using Firebase Database. In my Firebase Database I have a node like `xxxxxx_yyyyyy`, where `xxxxxx` represents first user ID and `yyyyyy` represents second user ID. Now I want to retrieve only nodes which contains `xxxxxx_` from my database. I don't know how to do this. Because all I know is Firebase gives only equalsTo() method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no query like contain(). I recommend to change node structure (locating yyyyy under xxxxx).

Answer (score 0):

There Is no Query Like Contains in Fire base.! 
if you dnt want to change structure of your node you can Store Data in list and then simply use list.contains() you will get your desired Result.!

```
  HtBVbQP0qMSrCStroYsIiMSuhMC3 //node userID 
     Name:XXXXXXX
```

You can get this Data by using  `orderbychild(XXXXXX);`

Answer (score 0):

There is no `contain()` method, however, you can solve this problem in two ways:

1. Using the `split()` method from `String` class.
2. Using `Regex Pattern`

Here is the code:

```
    String firebaseField = "xxxxxx_yyyyyy";

    String[] data = firebaseField.split("_");
    System.out.print("Using split method: ");
    for(String part : data) {
        if (part.equals("xxxxxx")) {
            System.out.print(part + " ");
            //Add your logic
        }
    }
```

Or

```
    System.out.print("\nUsing Regex Pattern: ");
    Pattern datePattern = Pattern.compile("_");
    data = datePattern.split(firebaseField);
    for(String part : data) {
        if (part.equals("xxxxxx")) {
            System.out.print(part + " ");
            //Add your logic
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.